# Get notifications when an NSData/CFData object is being read?

Tags: ios, macos, nsdata, core-foundation, cfdata

I'm using an API that takes a `CFData` object, and I need to generate the data on the fly, which is a time consuming operation. The `CFData` is read by the consumer in a random, non-contiguous manner, and it rarely actually needs the entire length of the data -- it just needs certain random pieces of it.

I would like to improve performance by only actually generating the bits that are requested by the consumer, as they are requested.

Is there any way to subclass `CFData`/`NSData` such that I would get callbacks as data chunks are being read and generate them on the fly?

**Update:** Unfortunately the consumer is 3rd party code and so other classes aren't an option, unless they're somehow magically compatible with `CFData`.

Comment: Another alternative to consider is CGDataProvider.

Comment: @jtbandes unfortunately I have no control over the consumer code, and it only accepts CFData. I just updated the question.

Comment: Well, then this may not be possible without some serious hackery. Is the 3rd-party code open-source? Can you write your own replacement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you're going to like the answers you get here. You seem to be cornered with respect to options.

#### What we know about your situation

1. The client's code cannot accept a different type / class
2. `CFData` is a CoreFoundation C-type and doesn't have a runtime to play with
3. The client probably uses CoreFoundation symbols to read this data

   1. *If you're lucky, it's through the Foundation APIs in Obj-C which has a runtime*
4. `CFData` wraps a `void *` to data, but has some padding at the beginning (likely a struct) that'll be difficult to mimic if you tried to create a `CFData` proxy object

---

It's going to be very difficult to accomplish what you want without some clever, un-maintainable, and overall dangerous symbol hackery I won't even bother to get into.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you're wanting something more like [`NSInputStream`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSInputStream_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSInputStream):

> NSInputStream is a subclass of NSStream that provides read-only stream
>   functionality.
>
> NSInputStream is “toll-free bridged” with its Core Foundation
>   counterpart, CFReadStreamRef. For more information on toll-free
>   bridging, see Toll-Free Bridging.
>
> #### Subclassing Notes
>
> NSInputStream is an abstract superclass of a class cluster consisting of concrete subclasses of NSStream that
>   provide standard read-only access to stream data. Although
>   NSInputStream is probably sufficient for most situations requiring
>   access to stream data, you can create a subclass of NSInputStream if
>   you want more specialized behavior (for example, you want to record
>   statistics on the data in a stream).

Comment: Please see update -- unfortunately I have no control over the consumer code, and so switching to another class isn't possible in this case.

Answer (score 0):

`CFDataRef` and `NSData` are toll-free bridged. That mean, you can pass `NSData` instance into code, that expect `CFData`.

`NSData` is a class cluster. That mean, you can subclass it, and implement only primitive methods and initializers. For `NSData` primitive methods are:

```
@property (readonly) NSUInteger length;
@property (readonly) const void *bytes NS_RETURNS_INNER_POINTER;
```

You must also implement some `init`... method, that will initialize your instance.

All other `NSData` functionality is provided in categories. You still can override any method and provide your own implementation.

As an option, you can start from `NSData` subclass that will delegate any methods to internal `NSData` instance, which you can store in property. In this way you can observe 3rd party code behavior and investigate which methods you need to override.

Still, you will need a lot of luck to be able to implement what you want. But it may be possible.

As an example, I've created following dummy `NSData` subclass:

```
@interface MyData : NSData
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSData *innerData;
@end

@implementation MyData

- (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _innerData = data;
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSUInteger)length {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return self.innerData.length;
}

- (const void *)bytes {
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromSelector(_cmd));
    return self.innerData.bytes;
}

@end
```

When I invoke following code:

```
NSData *originalData = [NSData dataWithBytes:"hello" length:5];
MyData *myData = [[MyData alloc] initWithData:originalData];
NSLog(@"%ld", CFDataGetLength((CFDataRef)myData));
```

`length` method of my subclass is called.